# MySQL Error 1265: Data truncated for column 'name' at row #

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to read a file and use the data in it for one of my tables.  However, I get the error stating: ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'ERA' at row 1.

I understand what the error means - that the data is to large for the data type.  However, the columns 'ERA' is the last piece of information for the first row in the .txt file.  (what's in .txt file below).

So I tested it by manually inputting the same information in the first row.  it accepted the data just fine.  So I deleted the manually added row and then tried to load only 1 single row from the .txt file.  This worked.

***I only get the error when I have more than 1 row of data to load from the file.***

I figure it has something to do with it reading the Enter Key value or something, but I have no idea how to fix it to be readable.  Does something need to be put at the end of each row in the file?  If so, what?

(Note about me:  I am only learning MySQL temporarily to get past a certain point in my life.  I only have a beginner's knowledge on it since its not my plan to use it in the future.  So if there is something special I have to do in MySQL to fix the issue, please give a clear example.  At least enough information for me to Google more examples)

Contents of .txt file:

```
Arizona Diamondbacks    1998    1819    914 905 1   1   8379    62131   16137   1933    .260    8422    4.26

Atlanta Braves  1876    19764   9786    9825    17  3   88243   677310  176434  12203   .260    87693   3.65

Baltimore Orioles   1901    16861   7965    8786    7   26  72633   572146  148197  11335   .259    77029   3.99

Boston Red Sox  1901    16848   8657    8108    12  7   77981   575510  153781  11671   .267    75352   3.88

Chicago Cubs    1876    19796   10103   9537    16  2   91616   678492  178828  12479   .264    88269   3.66

Chicago White Sox   1901    16855   8476    8276    6   3   73603   570404  148833  9662    .261    72730   3.73

Cincinnati Reds 1882    19382   9766    9480    10  5   87300   661241  173334  11533   .262    86119   3.71

Cleveland Indians   1901    16863   8571    8201    5   2   76441   575356  153431  11338   .267    74685   3.82

Colorado Rockies    1993    2565    1203    1362    1   0   13426   88540   24687   2944    .279    14085   5.17

Detroit Tigers  1901    16885   8497    8295    10  4   78163   575699  152746  12050   .265    77194   3.96

Florida Marlins 1993    2561    1214    1347    2   2   11353   87282   22744   2392    .261    12150   4.39

Houston Astros  1962    7526    3754    3766    1   0   31521   255339  65127   5533    .255    31387   3.75
```

(Note about the file: in the actual file, there is no space between each line as in it doesn't look double spaced.  At the end of each row, enter is pressed in the file. The space between each data is a tab (which seems to be fine). The file is saved from Notepad if that also has something to do with it.)

The Table stats:

```
Field | Type | Null | Default |

<------------------------------------------------->

Team | varchar(50) | YES | NULL |

FirstYear | int(11) | YES | NULL |

G | int(11) | YES | NULL |

W | int(11) | YES | NULL |

L | int(11) | YES | NULL |

Pennants | int(11) | YES | NULL |

WS | int(11) | YES | NULL |

R | int(11) | YES | NULL |

AB | int(11) | YES | NULL |

H | int(11) | YES | NULL |

HR | int(11) | YES | NULL |

AVG | float | YES | NULL |

RA | int(11) | YES | NULL |

ERA | float | YES | NULL |
```

Comment: How are you importing it?

Comment: With the command -> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_location' INTO TABLE table_name;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What is most likely happening, is the default command expects the terminating character to be `'\n'` when it is really `'\r\n'`; Try this command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_location' INTO TABLE table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: Worked immediately.  Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Check the query values in database.
datatype may be mismatched in table column field and inserted values.
For example datatype of column field is double, then if you inserted float values that was successfully inserted but it gives the error 1265 with description "Data truncated for column 'XXXX' at row 1".

Answer (score -2):

Check for the value of that specific column and row in your data. There might be a data type mismatch, change it to other datatype.